# how to export a javascript variable to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a html file that calls a javascript function to get a 6 digit input from the user.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="ho.js"></script>
        <h1>Sample</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
            <input type="tel" id="realOTP" placeholder="Enter Your OTP"  maxlength="6">
            <input type="submit" value="Use OTP" onclick="compute()">
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the ho.js javascript file where the function is defined.

```
var a=10, arr=[];
var exports = module.exports = {};
function compute() {
    rOTP = document.getElementById('realOTP').value;
    if (rOTP.length == 0) {
        alert('Enter a value');
        return;
    };
    arr = String(rOTP).split("");
    console.log("Entered OTP -> " + arr);
    return arr;
}
    exports.array = compute.arr;//what should come here?
exports.r = a;
    console.log("a:" +a);
exports.fun =function(){
    console.log("in function");
    var mes = require("./ho").r;
    console.log("mes:"+mes);
    var mes2 = require("./ho").array;
    console.log("mes2:"+mes2);
}
```

Is it possible to export the return value of the javascript function ("arr" in this case) to the node js exports function similar to the global variable a=10. This is my main node file which i call after getting the value of "arr" via browser.

hoh.js

```
var call = require("./ho");
console.log("hoh:" +call.r);
call.fun();
```

This is the output I get when I run hoh.js:

```
C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Ultro>node hoh.js
a:10
hoh:10
in function
mes:10
mes2:undefined
```

Comment: Can you try `exports.array = compute()`

Comment: @JordanHendrix It looks like compute() is meant to be called by the submit button in his HTML.  exporting the result of compute like that will not allow the code to take into account modifications to the input with id "realOTP".

Comment: I'll get DOM errors, because compute is a Javascript function that runs on browser. When I assign it to node which runs off the browser will throw error like C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Ultro\ho.js:4
    rOTP = document.getElementById('realOTP').value;
           ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand your question. Are you trying to post the value to the server or something?  I thought that hoh.js was supposed to be another file on the client (I overlooked that you are trying to run it with node)

Comment: Yes @mrjohnsonengr, I'm trying to post a value to the server through javascript and get that value and process it with node.

Comment: Ok. Well you're a little far off and the pieces you are missing are a bit outside the scope of this question.  What you basically need to do is set up a node server which will accept the data, and then in your client, after compute happens, you need to create an XMLHttpRequest and post the data to the server with it.  I would recommend finding a tutorial for each of those aspects and working up to a complete example.

Comment: Actually this question is a model of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485539/how-to-make-global-variable-of-a-javascript-file-available-in-the-exports-functi) question. I've already set up a server, added routes via express.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.arr = arr;
```

Will export the array.  But the array gets re-assigned in compute.  If instead compute() mutates the array, you'll be able to access its contents in the exported array.

Change `arr = String(rOTP).split("");` to `arr.push.apply(arr, String(rOTP).split(""));` so that computer() mutates a rather than re-assigning it.

**Alternatively, export a getter**

Alternatively, you can export a getter which will allow you to continute re-assigning arr as much as you want.  This code example could also be written using ES6 fat arrow syntax; I simply assume you are restricted to ES5 though.

```
exports.getArr = function() { return arr; }
```

Comment: I've tried your edits in the code but I'm still unable to get the value of "arr". This is my output : C:\Users\Balajee\Desktop\project\Ultro>node hoh.js
a:10
hoh:10
in function
mes:10
mes2:

Comment: When I use getArr, i'm getting mes2: undefined

Comment: Right. See my comment on your question.  Are you trying to post the value to the server?  It looks like you are trying to access the value from the client some time after the input button has been pressed.

Comment: Exactly @mrjohnsonengr, I'll call the hoh.js through node to access the value of "arr" from the client, after getting input from the browser